# How does this function work? (BST recursion)

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

Didn't find a suitable title, forgive me for that,
anyways

Im trying to analyze a recursion function of BST, which returns 1.

After my bad calculations, I got return value of 0, I want to understand what am I doing here wrong.

We call the function like that from `main.c`: `func_3(root, 9);`

So **sum = 9**

**Here's the block of code:**

```
int func_3(struct node* node, int sum)
 {
        if (node == NULL) 
              return(sum == 0);
        else 
        {
            int subSum = sum - node->data;
            return (func_3(node->left, subSum) ||  func_3(node->right, subSum));

         }
 }
```

**Here's the BST:**
[image]

**My calculations:**
func(5,9) -> func3(3,4) -> func(1,1) -> returns subTree = sum = 0.

Comment: Please edit the question so indentation will be presented correctly

Comment: @dear_tzvi I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Probably they meant: indent your code properly so it isn't an unreadable mess.

Comment: @Lundin I don't see any mess here. everything has been added to the post properly and clearly.

Comment: @Ilan Aizelman WS  What does this function do?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That is what I'm trying to analyze.

Comment: @Ilan Aizelman WS  The function should have a description.

Comment: Did you check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183985/recursive-insertion-of-bst

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This function is trying to see if there is any path (root to a leaf node) whose sum of values is equal to `sum`

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS are you misreading the code? Your statement `returns subTree = sum = 0` is incorrect, it is `returns subTree = sum == 0`

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you are mistaken Weather. my code is fine.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS I did not mean your code is wrong, I mean you are mis-reading what it does. The statement at the bottom where you tried to understand, says it should return 0. Apart from that I have no idea what the question is asking. You said you think it should return 0.

Comment: Yes. If I've read the sum == 0 more carefully, I would understand that it will actually return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function returns `1` if there is a path (`root node` to a `leaf node`) whose sum of values is equal to `sum`.

In your function call `func_3(root, 9)` in main, what you are trying to do is check if there is any path in your binary tree, such that the sum of values of all the nodes in that path is equal to 9.

There is such path, which is the leftmost path (5->3->1), so your function will return 1.

This is how it is returning 1. First call is

```
func_3(node, 9)
```

where `node` is pointing to root node of this tree, i.e. root node with value `5`.

Here node is not null. So,

subSum = 9 - 5 = 4.

Next call is

```
func3(node, 4)
```

where `node` is pointing to node with value `3` (left child of node of previous call)

Here again node is not null, So,

subSum = 4 - 3 = 1

Next call is

```
func3(node, 1)
```

where `node` is pointing to node with value `1` (left child of node of previous call)

Here again node is not null, So,

subSum = 1 - 1 = 0

Next call is

```
func_3(node, 0)
```

where `node` is pointing to `NULL` (left child of node of previous call)

However this time `node` is `NULL`, and since `sum == 0` is true, it will return `1`, And this return value is returned all the way up the recursion and finally to `main`.

Comment: Thank you very much sps!

Comment: wc. Also, one more thing to note. The reasoning you gave at the end of your question (for return value being 0) shows that you are confused about when this function can return 0. For this funciton to return 0, it should traverse `each and every` path. That is because you have `return func_3(node->left, subSum) || func_3(node->right, subSum)`, so you can see, if `1` is not returned from `func_3(node->left, subSum)`, then `func_3(node->right, subSum)` is called. So you see that for a `0` to be returned `every` path is traversed.

Comment: Excellent explanation! I understand it even better now. Thank you `sps` !